# Autolayout UIVisualEffectView Delay

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout, uivisualeffectview

I have a UIImageView in Storyboard. Right after that in document outline hierarchy, I have a UIVisualEffectView both set to Center X, Center Y, Equal width and height to the super view which is the top view in the viewcontroller.

This works. The problem is, while rotation between portrait and landscape I can see a sneak peak of the under UIImageView for few milliseconds. In other words UIImageView gets layout faster than UIVisualEffetView enough that the user can see the un-blurred image.

Is there any fix to this?

Comment: have you tried pinning to the superview edges instead of center x+y , equal w,h

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Set Autolayout of the first view(UIImageView) in the hierarchy with the top view and the second view(UIVisualEffectView) with the first view. This way the UIVisualEffectView will layout according to the UIImageView.

Hope this helps.